# Is there a way to batch-check the existence of specific object versions in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, cloud-storage, r-paws

This post comes from my recent attempt at solving https://github.com/ropensci/targets/issues/1172 (more background: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/cloud-storage.html). In a reproducible pipeline, the `targets` R package needs to check the existence of a specific version of each AWS S3 object in its data store. The version of a given object is the version ID recorded in the metadata, which may or may not be the most current version in the bucket. Currently, `targets` accomplishes this by sending a HEAD request for each relevant object-version pair.

Is there a more efficient/batched way to do this for each version/object pair? `list_object_versions()` returns every version of every object of interest, which is way too many versions to download efficiently, and neither `list_objects()` nor `list_objects_v2()` return any version IDs at all.

Comment: As you've discovered, no such functionality exists.  Generally, if you want to check if many objects have changed, you can cache and compare the ETag, or use a [external metadata store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/) which can make sense in some scenarios.